# Accessing application delegate variable delays view loading in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, uiapplicationdelegate

I am a newbie to Swift and i have started my new project with Swift. I am facing a delay issue while loading a viewcontroller.

On the application delegate i have a variable

```
      var  allTerms: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]?
```

This allTerms is populated with data from a local json file of 900Kb. The total json data count is 800.

So far i have a home screen and a second view. From the home screen when i navigate to second screen i need to access this allTerms from the application delegate. Referring to great tutorials,i was able to access the allTerms variable from the application delegate

```
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate!
        self.tableData = (appDelegate.allTerms! as NSArray) as? Array
```

However doing so this is causing a noticeable delay in loading the secondview , which doesnot happen if i comment the line

```
self.tableData = (appDelegate.allTerms! as NSArray) as? Array
```

Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create a separate data manager class instead of storing it in the app delegate. You could use something like this:

```
class DataManager {
var  allTerms: [[String:AnyObject]]?

class var sharedInstance: DataManager {
    struct Singleton {
        static let instance = DataManager()
    }
    return Singleton.instance
}
// You can access allTerms by calling DataManager.sharedInstance.allTerms

}
```

This probably won't solve your lag, but it's a good practice to make a DataManager class to store things. I also rewrote your allTerms declaration to use the short form for the dictionary.